# android openOrCreateDatabase only works in emulator

Tags: android, sqlite, ddms

I've noticed that openOrCreateDatabase only works in the emulator and not on the phone, when I right-click the project and "Run as Android application." I've checked the DDMS and the database is successfully created through the emulator but not an actual device. When testing on the phone, I get no error message at all. And yes, I do know about the database helper class, which I've also tried, again with no error message. So I'm wondering, is there a permissions issue in place? Some sort of configuration that needs to be set so as to create a SQLite database while testing on the phone? Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

P.S. I was following along with this tutorial: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OUoGnvz_Yw4

---

Edited to add the code:
Here it is... works fine in the emulator, nothing happens on the device. Any help is appreciated. Thanks again.

```
package com.solitario.dbtest1;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.openOrCreateDatabase("dbtest1.db",MODE_PRIVATE,null);
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS FunnyNames (email VARCHAR, firstName VARCHAR, lastName VARCHAR);");
        db.close();
    }
}
```

---

Edit in response to Rob's question:
Paying closer attention to my LogCat I saw the following two lines:

```
08-07 21:44:33.439: D/Database(2936): dbopen(): path = /data/data/com.solitario.dbtest1/databases/dbtest1.db, flag = 6
08-07 21:44:33.439: D/Database(2936): dbopen(): path = /data/data/com.solitario.dbtest1/databases/dbtest1.db, free size = 888
```

I tried to pull the database by typing this into my terminal, and got a "Permission denied."

```
solitario@ubuntu:~/sdk/platform-tools$ sudo ./adb pull /data/data/com.solitario.dbtest1/databases/dbtest1.db
failed to copy '/data/data/com.solitario.dbtest1/databases/dbtest1.db' to './dbtest1.db': Permission denied
```

So figuring terminal would give me a different response if I tried to pull a file which did not exist, I went into my droid settings, cleared the app's data but did not uninstall the app. Then tried again to pull the database from the terminal, and got a "does not exist."

```
solitario@ubuntu:~/sdk/platform-tools$ sudo ./adb pull /data/data/com.solitario.dbtest1/databases/dbtest1.db
remote object '/data/data/com.solitario.dbtest1/databases/dbtest1.db' does not exist
```

So that would seem that it did in fact create the database, but that DDMS does not show you when a database has been created, nor will terminal allow you to pull it so as to look at it.

So, I would like to revise my question... when building an android app and testing on an actual device, how does one verify that your commands have succeeded? What tool is there to verify my queries have been executed on the droid?

Thanks again for reading and your responses!

Comment: Hi there, I've worked with Android DBs a fair bit and I'm not sure how to help.  It seems to me like this problem is a good candidate for creating and posting your minimal example of failure.

Comment: Post some code so we can see what you're doing.

Comment: Is it not creating the db, or are you just not able to navigate to the db on the device? The application directory where the db is created on a real (unrooted) device is not visible to you.

Answer (score 2):

To view your database when debugging on a non-rooted device you need to copy it to a publicly visible location, like the SD card.

You can use code something like the following to copy your db to the SD card (don't forget to disable this code before you ship). Call this at the point where you want to verify what state your db is in.

```
String sourcePath = "/data/data/com.solitario.dbtest1/databases/dbtest1.db";
File sourceFile = new File(sourcePath);

FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);

String outFilePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/dbtest1.db";

OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(outFilePath);

byte[] buff = new byte[1024];
int len;
while ((len = fis.read(buff)) > 0) {
    output.write(buff, 0, len);
}
output.flush();
output.close();
fis.close();
```

You may need to modify the output directory if you don't have an SD card in your device.

Once you have it on the SD card you can copy it to your development machine using DDMS in Eclipse.

Once it is on your development machine [SQLite DB browser](http://sqlitebrowser.sourceforge.net/) can open the db and browse/query it etc.